# Target-Action with Xcode storyboards for desktop apps

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I've got a button in a toolbar that I'd like to use to control the state (expanded/collapsed) of the right-hand-side split of a split-view. In a xib-based project this is trivial, but I'm using storyboards, and can't work out what the best approach is.

[image]

The key limitation is the fact that I'm not able to create target-action connections between objects in different scenes. As I see it, this leaves me with three options:

1. Have the window controller handle the expand/collapse request - this seems inappropriate - what's the window controller got to do with the state of the split view?
2. Have the window 'collect' the action and refer it on to the split-view controller for processing - this is better but to me it still seems like bad design to have the window controller in this process at all.
3. Add a custom action to the responder chain, and connect the button's selector to the responder chain. This is what I've done, but it still seems like a distant second-best compared with the xib-style approach - a direct drag-and-drop between objects.

I suppose as I was hoping that storyboards would just make everything easier - am I now right in thinking that this target-action dilemma is a genuine shortcoming of the storyboard approach, and that I just need to get used to one of the above?

Comment: I want to like story boards but they don't quite seem ready for general purpose just yet. Nice question +1